# Matlab: mapshow and non-string geometry field

Tags: string, matlab, struct, geometry

I am creating a table to store points, then transforming the table to a struct and using mapshow() to plot it.

The following error is thrown:

> An element of geographic data structure S has a non-string 'Geometry' field.

Even if the class() function returns string.

Am I missing something stupid or where is my error? Thanks to everyone!

```
points = table('Size', [0 4], ...
                  'VariableNames', {'Geometry', 'X', 'Y', 'Type'}, ...
                  'VariableTypes', {'string', 'double', 'double', 'string'});

newPoint.Geometry = 'Point';
newPoint.X = 20;
newPoint.Y = 50;
newPoint.Type = 'Source';

points = [points; struct2table(newPoint)];

pointsSymbol = makesymbolspec('Point', {'Type', 'Source', 'Marker', '^', 'Color', [0 0 1], 'MarkerSize', 10}, ...
                                       {'Type', 'Sink',   'Marker', 'v', 'Color', [1 0 0], 'MarkerSize', 10});

pointsStruct = table2struct(points);
class(pointsStruct.Geometry) % 'string'

mapshow(pointsStruct, 'SymbolSpec', pointsSymbol); % error
```

I am currently using Matlab R2019a prerelease.

Comment: I don't have the same error as you... `color` is not defined.

Comment: Yes sorry, it is a class that I use for colors. I edited out that dependency from the code.

Comment: OK, thanks. But I cant' help since it requires **Mapping Toolbox**. You should warn people about that in your question.